# While loop doesn't exit even with false conditions applied

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop

My program won't exit even upon returning the wrong value in the while loop. What should I do? I just started programming and can't figure it out. I've googled for answers and copied tutorials and it still won't work. I'm assuming there is some conflicting code or syntax errors but I can't find it. Please help.

```cpp
using namespace std;

int power(int baseNum, int powNum){
    int result = 1;
    for(int i=0; i<powNum; i++){
        result = result * baseNum;
    }
    return result;
}

int main() {
    char restart;
    while(restart = 'r')
    {
        int numb1;
        int numb2;
        char op;

        cout << "Enter the first number: ";
        cout << endl;
        cin >> numb1;

        cout << "Enter operator: ";
        cout << endl;
        cin >> op;

        cout << "Enter the second number: ";
        cout << endl;
        cin >> numb2;

        switch(op){
            case '+':
                cout << "Sum = " << numb1 + numb2 << endl;
                break;
            case '-':
                cout << "Difference = " << numb1 - numb2 << endl;
                break;
            case '*':
                cout << "Product = " << numb1 * numb2 << endl;
                break;
            case '/':
                cout << "Quotient = " << numb1 / numb2 << endl;
                break;
            case '^':
                cout << "Result = " << power(numb1, numb2) << endl;
                break;
            default:
                cout << "Error: Invalid Operator!" << endl;
        }

        cout << "Press [R] to restart." << endl;
        cin >> restart;
    }

    cout << "the end" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use == instead of = in your loop condition.

Comment: `=` is assignment, `==` is comparison for equality; You also need to initialize `restart` with a value (e.g. `char restart{};`) before using it in the `while` condition. Not doing so causes undefined behavior, as reading of indeterminate values always does.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The bug is here: `while(restart = 'r')` it should be `while(restart == 'r')`